# Struts 1.0 migration to Spring boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, jakarta-ee, struts-1

I have tried to migrate from struts 1 to spring boot. Is it possible migrate with set of steps. Do we have any tools to migrate?

Comment: I highly doubt that such a tool exists. Struts' 1 EOL was, what, 15 years ago or so? I think that effort to make such a tool would be enormous and potential market very small.

Comment: Just google it. There are a lot of articles like this one http://www.ijettcs.org/Volume2Issue2/IJETTCS-2013-04-10-091.pdf

Comment: AFAIK there are no tools to go from S1 to Spring Boot (SB was developed after S1 was EOLed). There may be very limited tooling for converting S1 to older Spring MVC, but I doubt there's much, because they don't have much in common.